# Add payment specific fee in Magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How can we add extra fee on Cash on delivery payment method in magento2.
I tried to convert Phoenix COD in magento2 but not getting the result.

Comment: We can try this module: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_Payment_Fee

Answer (score 4):

You can try with **MSP_CashOnDelivery** module: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CashOnDlivery

It add an additional *Cash On Delivery* payment method that allows you to load a csv configuration file, just like the Table Rate shipping, and set the additional fee.

Currently I found some bug, but it worth a try.

To install it via composer:

```
$ composer require msp/cashondelivery
$ composer update
$ php bin/magento module:enable MSP_Common
$ php bin/magento module:enable MSP_CashOnDelivery
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a module to add a payment fee by a specific payment method. You can add a payment fee for any payment methods(online or offline).

Recently I added lots of new features like add tax, support multi-currency, set sort order, etc.

**Look at this: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-paymentfee**